# Can I avoid annotating my dataset for object recognition?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, dataset, object-detection-api

I've been working on image classification with deep learning models (CNN with keras and tensorflow as back end) such as AlexNet and ResNet. I learned a lot about the whole dataset, learning, testing processes.

I'm now shifting to object detection and have done a lot of research. I came across R-CNN, Fast R-CNN, Faster R-CNN, Mask R-CNN and different versions of YOLO networks. I noticed that these object detection networks require dataset annotation instead of the former simply needing to have cropped images stored in corresponding files.
Is there any way to accomplish object detection without having to annotate dataset?

Answer (score 0):

No, not really, Deep Learning is not magic, you need bounding box annotations. The field of research that deals with this problem is *Weakly Supervised Object Detection*, and its a research field, there are no solutions that perform as well as using an annotated dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Deep Learning is part of a broader family of machine learning methods based on artificial neural networks. **Learning can be supervised, semi-supervised or unsupervised**. To get a decent result you have to train your model using annotated dataset. Otherwise DL without learning, why would it be called a Deep Learning?

If you want to avoid data annotation, what are you looking for is a **Traditional Computer Vision** technique. It could be vary depends on your need.

For example if you want to detect simple object, you can extract them using [**Simple Blob Detector**](https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/) . 
Or if you want to detect an identical object, you can use Image Comparison technique such as [**Template Matching**](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html) or [**Feature Matching** using SURF](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.3/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html)

Comment: As for SURF, I recently published the original source code https://github.com/herbertbay/SURF. It should be more robust than the OpenCV version.